# How to make a "return" end function inside function?

Tags: php

If function `alfa` calls function `beta`, how would I make a `return` statement inside function `beta` end function `alfa`?

For example:

```
function alfa() {
    beta();
    return ('message 2');
}

function beta() {
    return ('message 1');
}
```

When running `echo alfa($x)` I want the function to stop and return just `message 1`. 
But I want the `return beta ();` to be ignored and code continue in case `beta()` has no return. How to do that?

Comment: return beta() inside alfa(). Or assign the return value to a variable where you can process it.

Comment: `return` is not a function, you should just be writing `return 'message 2';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
function alfa() {
//code...
return beta ();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Do this:

```
function alfa() {
   $beta=beta ();
   if(!empty($beta)){
      return $beta;
   }else{
     //code...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for input! I was not clear, re-did the question. I want the return beta (); to be ignored and code continue in case beta() has no return. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Return function `beta()` from `alpha()`:

```
function alfa() {
//code...    
return beta ();
}
```

Comment: I was not clear, re-did the question. I want the `return beta ();` to be ignored and code continue in case `beta()` has no return. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

either test the return value from the inner function (preferred) or throw an exception:

test return value and signal parent what to do:

```
function alfa() {
  var retVal = beta();
  return (retVal) ? retVal : ('message 2');
}
```

throw an exception (not 100% valid, but will work as a hack)

```
function alfa()
{
 try {
   beta();
   return('message 2'); 
 }
 catch (err)
 {
   return err;
 } 
}  

function beta()
{
   throw 'message 1';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `return beta()` to be ignored if `return` is true and to continue if `return` is false, this might help you:

```
 <?PHP

function alfa() {
   if(! beta() ){      
     return ('code continue since beta has no return');
   } else {
       return beta();
   }
}

function beta() {
    return ('beta has return');
}
$x = alfa();
echo $x;

?>
```